# Decode .ilearner from Azure

Tags: python, azure

I would like to ask for solutions for the problem with decoding .ilearner file downloaded via API from Microsoft Azure ML.  The error I am receiving looks like this:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-157aac1e9b7a>", line 162, in <module>
   invokeBatchExecutionService()
 File "<ipython-input-1-157aac1e9b7a>", line 157, in invokeBatchExecutionService
   processResults(result)
 File "<ipython-input-1-157aac1e9b7a>", line 51, in processResults
   saveBlobToFile(url3, "The results for " + outputName)
 File "<ipython-input-1-157aac1e9b7a>", line 28, in saveBlobToFile
   f.write(response.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore'))
 File "D:\XXXXXX\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
   return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0
" UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u053e' in position 1463: character maps to <undefined>"
```

My full code looks like this:

```
import urllib.request
import json
import time
from azure.storage.blob import *

def printHttpError(httpError):
    print("The request failed with status code: " + str(httpError.code))

    # Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
    print(httpError.info())

    print(json.loads(httpError.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore')))
    return

def saveBlobToFile(blobUrl, resultsLabel):
    output_file = "C:/XXX/API/output.csv" # Replace this with the location you would like to use for your output file, and valid file extension (usually .csv for scoring results, or .ilearner for trained models)
    print("Reading the result from " + blobUrl)
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(blobUrl)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
        printHttpError(error)
        return
#    print("Response:  " + response)
    with open(output_file, "w+") as f:
#        print(response.read())
        f.write(response.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore'))
    print(resultsLabel + " have been written to the file " + output_file)
    return

def processResults(result):
    first = True
    results = result["Results"]
#    print(" Results : "  + results)
    for outputName in results:
        result_blob_location = results[outputName]
        sas_token = result_blob_location["SasBlobToken"]
        base_url = result_blob_location["BaseLocation"]
        relative_url = result_blob_location["RelativeLocation"]

        print("The results for " + outputName + " are available at the following Azure Storage location:")
        print("BaseLocation: " + base_url)
        print("RelativeLocation: " + relative_url)
        print("SasBlobToken: " + sas_token)

        if (first):
            first = False
            url3 = base_url + relative_url + sas_token
            saveBlobToFile(url3, "The results for " + outputName)
#        first = True
    return

def uploadFileToBlob(input_file, input_blob_name, storage_container_name, storage_account_name, storage_account_key):
    blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=storage_account_name, account_key=storage_account_key)

    print("Uploading the input to blob storage...")
    blob_service.create_blob_from_path(storage_container_name, input_blob_name, input_file)

def invokeBatchExecutionService():
    storage_account_name = "XXX" # Replace this with your Azure Storage Account name
    storage_account_key = "XXX # Replace this with your Azure Storage Key
    storage_container_name = "XXX" # Replace this with your Azure Storage Container name
    connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" + storage_account_name + ";AccountKey=" + storage_account_key

    api_key = "XXX” # Replace this with the API key for the web service
    url = "https://uswestcentral.services.azureml.net/subscriptions/75b6fa4e098c4ad88df85a3533530bd4/services/4ed857d52f3140e1b422e6e986437b6e/jobs"

    uploadFileToBlob("C:/XXX/API/input.csv", # Replace this with the location of your input file, and valid file extension (usually .csv)
        "input2.csv", # Replace this with the name you would like to use for your Azure blob; this needs to have the same extension as the input file 
        storage_container_name, storage_account_name, storage_account_key);

    payload = {
            "Inputs": {
                    "input1": 
                    {
                      "ConnectionString": connection_string,
                        "RelativeLocation": "/" + storage_container_name + "/input.csv"
                    },
            },

            "Outputs": {
                    "output1":
                    {
                        "ConnectionString": connection_string,
                        "RelativeLocation": "/" + storage_container_name + "/output.csv" # Replace this with the location you would like to use for your output file, and valid file extension (usually .csv for scoring results, or .ilearner for trained models)
                    },
                    "output2":
                    {
                        "ConnectionString": connection_string,
                        "RelativeLocation": "/" + storage_container_name + "/output.ilearner" # Replace this with the location you would like to use for your output file, and valid file extension (usually .csv for scoring results, or .ilearner for trained models)
                    },
            },

        "GlobalParameters": {
        }
    }

    body = str.encode(json.dumps(payload))
    headers = { "Content-Type":"application/json", "Authorization":("Bearer " + api_key)}
    print("Submitting the job...")

    # submit the job
    req = urllib.request.Request(url + "?api-version=2.0", body, headers)

    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
        printHttpError(error)
        return

    result = response.read()
    job_id = result.decode("utf8", 'ignore')[1:-1]
    print("Job ID: " + job_id)

    # start the job
    print("Starting the job...")
    body = str.encode(json.dumps({}))
    req = urllib.request.Request(url + "/" + job_id + "/start?api-version=2.0", body, headers)
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
        printHttpError(error)
        return

    url2 = url + "/" + job_id + "?api-version=2.0"

    while True:
        print("Checking the job status...")
        req = urllib.request.Request(url2, headers = { "Authorization":("Bearer " + api_key) })

        try:
            response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        except urllib.error.HTTPError as error:
            printHttpError(error)
            return

        result = json.loads(response.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore'))
        status = result["StatusCode"]
        if (status == 0 or status == "NotStarted"):
            print("Job " + job_id + " not yet started...")
        elif (status == 1 or status == "Running"):
            print("Job " + job_id + " running...")
        elif (status == 2 or status == "Failed"):
            print("Job " + job_id + " failed!")
            print("Error details: " + result["Details"])
            break
        elif (status == 3 or status == "Cancelled"):
            print("Job " + job_id + " cancelled!")
            break
        elif (status == 4 or status == "Finished"):
            print("Job " + job_id + " finished!")
#            print("Results:  " + results)
            processResults(result)
            break
        time.sleep(1) # wait one second
    return
invokeBatchExecutionService()
```

The code follows guideline described by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/retrain-models-programmatically I run the Python 3.5 script .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are downloading a file encoded as UTF-8, then writing the data to your local filesystem using the filesystem's default encoding (probably cp1252 or similar).  Writing to the local filesystem is failing because the data contains characters that cannot be encoded as cp1252.

```
 >>> s = '\u053e'
>>> s
'Ծ'

>>> s.encode('cp1252')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/XXXXXX/data36/lib/python3.6/encodings/cp1252.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u053e' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

One solution is to encode your output file as UTF-8 (you will need to remember to open the file as UTF-8 if you open it elsewhere in your code)

```
with open(output_file, "wb+", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(response.read())
```

Another approach might be to set the `errors` argument to open to handle encoding errors.  For example:

```
with open(output_file, "w+", errors="replace") as f:
    f.write(response.read().decode("utf8", 'ignore'))
```

will replace un-encodeable characters with a `?` character.